# Appending string from inner function to parent variable

Tags: php

I have a function and want to gather it's output log to email when done. It looks something like this:

```
function blabla() {
   $emailMessage = "some text";

   $emailMessage .= "some more text";

   function foo() {
     for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++) {
        $emailMessage .= 'Call #' . $x;
        // then doing an API call
        return $response; 
     }
   }

   $res = foo();

   $emailMessage .= "last line of text";

}
```

Now `$emailMessage` looks like this: `some text || some more text || last line of text`. The text from the inner function is not appended.

How can I get it to look like this: `some text || some more text || call #1 || call #2 ||... || last line of text`

------EDIT------

Thanks to @kamal pal I used a global variable. Result looks like this:

```
function blabla() {
       global $emailMessage;
       $emailMessage = "some text";

       $emailMessage .= "some more text";

       function foo() {
         global $emailMessage;
         for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++) {
            $emailMessage .= 'Call #' . $x;
            // then doing an API call
            return $response; 
         }
       }

       $res = foo();

       $emailMessage .= "last line of text";

    }
```

Comment: Why would you use an "inner function"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to scope, Child function has it's own scope.

I can think of two options to accomplish this task:

- Using Global Variable
- Passing as Ref argument (see example below)

---

```
function blabla() {
    $emailMessage = "some text".PHP_EOL;
    $emailMessage .= "some more text".PHP_EOL;

    function foo(&$emailMessage) { // passed as ref argument
     for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++) {
            $emailMessage .= 'Call #' . $x.PHP_EOL;
            // then doing an API call
            //return $response; //it will exit function
     }
    }

    $res = foo($emailMessage);

    $emailMessage .= "last line of text".PHP_EOL;
    return $emailMessage;

}
echo blabla();
```

Demo: https://eval.in/571036

Comment: Ah OK thanks. So I went with a global var. I'm used to javascript scopes - that's why i thought global wouldn't be necessary ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you use completelly different variable name?

```
$emailResult .= 'Call #' . $x;
```

should be replaced with :

```
$emailMessage .= 'Call #' . $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is more clear an proper ( external ) function

```
function blabla() {
     $emailMessage = "some text";

     $emailMessage .= "some more text";

     $emailMessage = foo( $emailMessage);
     $emailMessage .= "last line of text";

}


function foo($emailMessage) {
  for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++) {
      $emailResult .= 'Call #' . $x;
      // then doing an API call
      return $emailResult; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the example. I hope this will help you.

```
<?php
echo blabla();


function blabla(){

$emailMessage = "some text|";

$emailMessage .= "some more text|";

function foo() {
$emailResult="";   
 for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++) {

    $emailResult .= "Call #".$x."|";

 }

    return $emailResult; 
 }

 $res = foo();

 $emailMessage .=$res; 

 $emailMessage .= "last line of text";

 return $emailMessage;

 }
 ?>
```